# git tracking one file changes

Tags: git, merge, repository, hook, pre-commit-hook

We have a large repo and a lots of commiters.

I want to track history of a single file.
Whenever someone changes it (push changes to my central repository), I get the email with diff and author name.

I know that making a pre-commit hook, to do so would resolve a problem for me, however I would have to propagate the script to all commiters.

Is there a pre-merge (or post-merge) hook?

Temporary solution would be a cron task checking every 10 min, who changes the file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a `post-merge` hook. Based on your description, however, you probably want to use the `post-receive` hook on your "central" repository. The [Pro-Git hooks page](http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html) describes it quite well.